# Creation of DSEGraphFrames in Java or Scala using a SparkSession

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, graphframes

I am trying to obtain a DSEGraphFrame of my DSE graphs in either java or scala. I am using the [blog documentation](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-graph-frame#DseGraphFrameBuilder), as follows

```
//load a graph in Java
DseGraphFrame graph = DseGraphFrameBuilder.dseGraph("test", spark); 


// load a graph in scala
val graph = spark.dseGraph("test_graph")
```

They both require a spark session (in scala is implicit). My question is  how can you create the  `SparkSession spark`? I tried already creating it by myself but the builder could not parse the master:

```
val spark  = SparkSession
.builder
.master("dse://<ip_address>")
.appName("DseGraphFrames")
.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Only applications launched with `dse spark-submit` can understand `dse://` master addresses. So make sure your launch is run by `dse spark-submit`

[DSE Doc Reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html#startingSpark__dseSparkSubmit)

Comment: I get `WARN  2017-08-11 16:25:58 org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkNodeConfiguration: Failed to fetch dynamic configuration from DSE` and the job is never executed, it never starts.

Comment: That means the node is either not analytics enabled or there is some other network or authentication problem

Comment: Analytics is enabled and I authentication should be ok since I can run Gremlin OLAP queries

Comment: that is not necessarily true ... You can always test quickly with the Spark REPL. Try dse spark, it will auto create the spark session object for you. But if you have auth that you aren't passing through or setting up it will fail to start.